# Return occurrences in multidimensional array

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to count the number of occurrences of a value in a multi-dimensional array?

I've got the following array:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'HrEmployee' => array(
            'id' => '7',
            'surname' => 'Basson',
            'name' => 'Andries'
        ),
        'Setup' => array(
            'color' => '004356',
            'size' => 12
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'HrEmployee' => array(
            'id' => '25',
            'surname' => 'Coetzee',
            'name' => 'Zandereen',
        ),
        'Setup' => array(
            'color' => 'CFCFCF',
            'size' => 8
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'HrEmployee' => array(
            'id' => '30',
            'surname' => 'De Kock',
            'name' => 'Theo',
        ),
        'Setup' => array(
            'color' => 'FFFFFF',
            'size' => 12
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'HrEmployee' => array(
            'id' => '31',
            'surname' => 'De Vaal',
            'name' => 'Chantell',
        ),
        'Setup' => array(
            'color' => '00FF00',
            'size' => 10
    ),
)
```

And I want to check the amount of times a certain size comes up, so it should return:

```
array(
    (int) 8 => (int) 1,
    (int) 10 => (int) 1,
    (int) 12 => (int) 2
)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: in my experience you really need to go deep. Loop on the array check the 'size' and count it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work like this:

```
$sizes = array();
foreach($arr as $v) {
    $s = $v['Setup']['size'];
    if(!isset( $sizes[$s])){
        $sizes[$s] = 0;
    }
    $sizes[$s]++;
}

print_r($sizes);
```

Comment: Awesome. Short and sweet. I over thought it in my head. Thanks!